# Using multiprocessing on Spark worker nodes

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm working in a Databricks environment where each worker node itself contains 4 cores. I have a task that I'm currently distributing to multiple workers, but I'd also like to leverage the individual cores in each worker as well. I'm currently trying to use `multiprocessing`, but runs into issues when executing on workers.

Here is an example function that runs expectedly without workers (on the driver node only):

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def times_two(x):
    return x*2

def parallel_run(input_list):
    with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
        out_list = pool.map(times_two, input_list)
    return out_list

l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
parallel_run(l1)
#>>Out: [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

However, this same function fails when trying to distribute it across the spark workers, resulting in a PicklingError:

```py
worker_nodes = 4
partitions = [l1 for i in range(worker_nodes)]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(partitions)
rdd_out = rdd.map(parallel_run)
rdd_out.collect()

#org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: '_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function double at 0x7f1e513131f0>: attribute lookup double on __main__ failed'
```

Is there any way to resolve this?